# Make a differentiable smooth sawtooth waveform

Tags: functions, function-construction

So, I am trying to understand the effect of sawtooth waveform on a mechanical system model. For example, a system of a plate and a box on it. And then we try to oscillate the plate.

In order to do that, I need to calculate the inertial force caused by the sawtooth waveform. And to find the inertial force, I need to calculate second derivative of sawtooth waveform. But because, you know, sawtooth waveform is not differentiable everywhere, I think make an approximation by using a smooth sawtooth waveform is enough. 'Smooth' here, I mean substitute upper tip and bottom tip of the sawtooth waveform into a circular curve of a certain radius.

So in short, my question is: How to make sawtooth wavefrom with a dull tip with Mathematica?
Here, although I said sawtooth, it would be better if applicable to any triangle waveform.

**EDIT:**

What if my triangle waveform is made from a completely arbitrary piecewise function such as  below

```
f = Piecewise[{{10 Mod[x, 1], 0 <= Mod[x, 1] < 0.1}, 
 {-(10/9) Mod[x, 1] + (10/9), 0.1 <= Mod[x, 1] < 1}}];
Plot[Evaluate[f], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Is it still possible?

Comment: there is a formula for a fourier series approximation here..http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ApproximationOfDiscontinuousFunctionsByFourierSeries/

Comment: @george2079 Unfortunately there are [Gibbs oscillations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon). It is very bad especially for derivatives. You need to introduce a smooth cut-off of the Fourier series with one of the [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). It is more difficult task then the Gaussian smoothing.

Comment: Of course.. I answered the title question w/o thinking about what he wanted to do with it.

Answer (score 34):

There are nice trigonometric formulas

```
δ = 0.01;

trg[x_] := 1 - 2 ArcCos[(1 - δ) Sin[2 π x]]/π;
sqr[x_] := 2 ArcTan[Sin[2 π x]/δ]/π;
swt[x_] := (1 + trg[(2 x - 1)/4] sqr[x/2])/2;

Plot[{TriangleWave[x], trg[x]}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[{SquareWave[x], sqr[x]}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
Plot[{SawtoothWave[x], swt[x]}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Previous answer**

You can use Gaussian smoothing and interpolation:

```
n = 1000;
δ = 0.02;

f = Interpolation[Prepend[#, {0.0, #[[-1, 2]]}], PeriodicInterpolation -> True] &@
     Transpose@{#, GaussianFilter[SawtoothWave[#], δ n {5, 1}, 
        Padding -> "Periodic"]} &@Range[1/n, 1.0, 1/n];

Plot[{SawtoothWave[x], f[x]}, {x, -1.2, 1.2}]
```

[image]

Here `n` is the number of interpolation points and `δ` is the standard deviation of the smoothing.

The second derivative:

```
Plot[f''[x], {x, -0.1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: congratulations on your 10k! :)

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks! I learned a lot of interesting things when I was earning this reputation :)

Comment: How to make a square wave function with 2 different width?

Answer (score 12):

One approach is to convolve the sawtooth wave directly with a Gaussian kernel. Since this can be done analytically, it is possible to return a function that is in closed form and hence can be differentiated without interpolation.

```
f = Integrate[SawtoothWave[t/10] Exp[-3 (t - x)^2] , {t, 0, 50}]
Plot[f, {x, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

You can control the amount of "rounding" at the top and bottom by the width of the `Exp` function. Defining the derivative:

```
df[x_] := D[f, x];
```

gives a closed form (though it is not exactly "simple"). The second derivative `D[df[x], x]` is also possible analytically. The method also works fine with `TriangleWave` instead of `SawtoothWave`.

Comment: It is exactly my fist idea! But I tried to integrate from -∞ to ∞ with no luck.

Comment: @ybeltukov -- I think this is why the built-in `Convolve` function doesn't work. But really, the problem doesn't require the full integral, only a portion is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The Fourier series of the sawtooth is differentiable, being made up of sines. However, as ybeltukov pointed out in a comment I did not read until he made me aware of it, Fourier series of piecewise continuously differentiable functions tend to overshoot a jump discontinuities, something which is called [Gibbs phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon). For that reason a Fourier series may not work very well for derivatives.

```
Plot[(2/Pi) Sum[(-1)^k Sin[2 Pi  k t]/k, {k, 10000}], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: sawtooth]

Be sure to read ybeltukov's comments below! I'm lifting the content into the answer since its so useful it deserves to be more visible. He suggests this solution:

```
(2/Pi) N@ Sum[(-1)^k Sin[2 Pi k t]/k BlackmanNuttallWindow[k/2/200], {k, 200}]
```

He plotted the second derivative and got this good looking graph:

[image: der]

Comment: Gibbs oscillations *not die out as the frequency increases*. See my comment under OP's question. The second derivative always has [heavy oscillating tails](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Do8.png). I think it is not good from the physical point of view.

Comment: @ybeltukov I did not see that comment, thank you. I had never heard of Gibbs phenomenon before, however I observed it when I plotted the function for a smaller range of k, but I thought it died out with higher ones. I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: Try something like `(2/Pi) N@ 
  Sum[(-1)^k Sin[2 Pi k t]/k BlackmanNuttallWindow[k/2/200], {k, 200}]`. It produces [nice shape](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xQy30.png) of the second derivative.

Comment: @ybeltukov Nice! I lifted it into the answer to make the answer more useful for future visitors.

Comment: Gibbs phenomenon only occurs at jump discontinuities. The Sawtooth wave is a continuous function, so there will be no Gibbs phenomenon for the function, but it will be present in the derivate (which has jump discontinuities).

Comment: @Aditya why do you claim the sawtooth wave is continuous function?

Comment: `Plot[(2/Pi) Sum[(-1)^k Sin[2 Pi k t]/k, {k, 100}], {t, 0, 3}]` will show Gibbs phenomenon for example, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

From an answer I saw on Mathematics stackexchange:

```
Plot[0*x - ArcTan[Tan[Pi*(x - 1/2)]]/Pi - 1/2, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/2690622) by Neuwirth describes a function that looks like a smoothened sawtooth. In *Mathematica* form, the function looks like this:

```
neuwirth[q_, x_] := Sin[x]/(1 + q^2 - 2 q Cos[x])
```

The paper considers the case `q = 1/2`, but it can be adjusted as seen fit, and the function can of course be rescaled and translated as well.

(I will have to defer a plot for the next edit, as I am on *gedanken Mathematica* currently.)