# Is there a better way to "grow" black tulips?

Tags: image-processing

I used the following clumsy way to obtain a bundle of black tulips. Is there a better way to do so?

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qclHT.jpg"]

cols = DominantColors[im, 9]
rim1 = RemoveBackground[im, {"Background", { cols[[2]], 0.1}}];
rim2 = RemoveBackground[rim1, {"Background", { cols[[3]], 0.1}}];
rim3 = RemoveBackground[rim2, {"Background", { cols[[5]], 0.1}}] ;
rim4 = RemoveBackground[rim3, {"Background", { cols[[7]], 0.1}}] ;
rim5 = RemoveBackground[rim4, {"Background", { cols[[8]], 0.1}}] ;
rim6 = RemoveBackground[rim5, {"Background", { cols[[9]], 0.1}}] ;
ImageCompose[  ColorConvert[im, "Grayscale"], rim6]
```

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One can apply here a smooth threshold with the criterion
$$
r + b > \alpha g.
$$

```
ImageApply[With[{t = (1 + Tanh[2 (1.5 #[[2]] - #[[1]] - #[[3]])])/2}, # t + 
    Mean[#] {1, 1, 1} (1 - t)] &, im]
```

[image]

The same with packed arrays:

```
Image@Transpose[#, {3, 1, 2}] &@
     With[{t = (1 + Tanh[2 (1.5 #2 - # - #3)])/
         2}, {# t, #2 t, #3 t} + 
       ConstantArray[(1 - t) Mean@{##}, 3]] & @@ 
   Transpose[#, {2, 3, 1}] &@ImageData@im
```

It is only 30% faster. I thing it is due to auto-compilation in `ImageApply`.

A darker version, which is closer to real-life black tulips:

```
With[{t = (1 - Tanh[4 (#[[1]] - #[[2]] - 0.5 #[[3]])])/2}, # t + 
    0.2 Mean[#] {1, 1, 1} (1 - t)] &, im]
```

[image]

Comment: wow. Those are believable in color. +1

Comment: How did you come up with the `Tanh` function? I'm by no means am image processing expert, but that can't be just a trial-and-error function... (+1 BTW)

Comment: @kale It is one of simple functions which gives a smooth version of `UnitStep`. Others are `ArcTan, Erf`, etc. Furthermore, these functions allow to construct [a smooth version of `TriangleWave` and so on](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38295/4678).

Comment: You could apply a mask for letting the leaves untouched. Something like `Opening[Binarize@
  ColorReplace[ColorSeparate[im, "HSB"][[1]], Black -> White, .003], 3]`