# Piecewise smooth rectangle pulse

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

I am wondering how to create a single rectangle pulse with nonlinear riding and falling edges on both sides.
I don't know whether it is better to do it piecewise or to mathematically transform the original rectangle with some function (e.g. a convolution).

So far, I' ve constructed my pulse with UnitStep functions :

```
trapezoid[t_] := 
 622.4*10^6*(t - 0.6*10^-12)*UnitStep[t - 0.6*10^-12] - 
  622.4*10^6*(t - 7.83*10^-12)*UnitStep[t - 7.83*10^-12] - 
  493.7*10^6*(t - 96.235*10^-12)*UnitStep[t - 96.235*10^-12] + 
  493.7*10^6*(t - 105.12*10^-12)*UnitStep[t - 105.12*10^-12]

Plot[trapezoid[t], {t, 0, 130*10^-12}, PlotRange -> {0, 5*10^-3}]
```

[image]

The point is that I need a preferably continuous shape so that I can Laplace transform it eventually.

Any help is welcome, because I am stuck defining the edges between the flat top and the 0 values before the rise.

Note: this is a very short pulse (100 ps long), if that is relevant, and the rise time is around 6 ps.

Thank you!

Tamás

Comment: Welcome! Please provide any already existing code (if available), so we can build on that. Do you have any more specific info on what you mean by "nonlinear"?

Comment: So far, I've constructed my pulse with UnitStep functions: `trapezoid[t_] := 622.4*10^6*(t - 0.6*10^-12)*UnitStep[t - 0.6*10^-12] - 622.4*10^6*(t - 7.83*10^-12)*UnitStep[t - 7.83*10^-12] - 493.7*10^6*(t - 96.235*10^-12)*UnitStep[t - 96.235*10^-12] + 493.7*10^6*(t - 105.12*10^-12)*UnitStep[t - 105.12*10^-12]` I'd like to make the edges not straight lines, rather "smooth" lines. Thank you!

Comment: Here is the plot command and range:
`Plot[trapezoid[t], {t, 0, 130*10^-12}, PlotRange -> {0, 5*10^-3}]`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hyperbolic tangents are useful for smooth step functions, e.g. `Plot[0.5 (Tanh[10 (x - 1)] - Tanh[10 (x - 3)]), {x, 0, 4}]`

Comment: At least closely related: [38293](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38293/5478)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The convolution approach is quite flexible. For example, here a Gaussian function is used to round the edges of the rectangle:

```
f[y_] = Convolve[Exp[-100 x^2], UnitStep[x - 1] - UnitStep[x - 2], x, y];
Plot[f[y], {y, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

One nice thing about the Gaussian is that it gives an analytic form, as you can see by querying f[y]

```
1/20 Sqrt[π] Erfc[10 - 10 y] - 1/20 Sqrt[π] Erfc[20 - 10 y]
```

You can find the Laplace Transform using:

```
LaplaceTransform[f[y], y, s]
```

Comment: Hello.

Thanks for your answer. I am wondering how I can transform the above to the tiny pulse I need (see original question).

I've tried a few things, but I lose the rectangle shape unfortunately.

Thank you!

P.S.: Have a wonderful new year!

Comment: To get a tiny pulse, use a very narrow distance between the unit steps and a very narrow Gaussian.

Comment: Can you provide any reference to the analytical solution or its derivation? Thanks

Comment: @Asheesh Sharma -- I don't know how Mathematica does the integration, but the answer is in f[y] above, containing a couple of Error functions and a couple of square roots.