# Smooth Boxcar function (Rectangle Pulse function)

Tags: functions, discontinuity, smoothing, engineering

There are some answers on how to get a smooth squarewave function. But I would like to have a smooth boxcar function or rectangle function with 2 different widths.: `wup`, and `wdown`

One solution is the Fourier Transform, but I prefer having an approximation with a smoothness factor.

Thank you very much.

Here is the non-smooth version. I would like to smooth it.
**Note that: this is not a square wave function (the smooth version is known [the solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38293/make-a-differentiable-smooth-sawtooth-waveform).** This is the boxcar function with 2 widths: up width is 2, and down width is 3.

[image]

```
pulse[h_, wup_, wdown_, t_] := 
 With[{period = wup + wdown, duty = wup/(wup + wdown)}, 
  h*UnitBox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty)]]
Plot[{pulse[1, 2, 3, t]}, {t, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None]
```

---

**Square Wave Pulse with Uniform Width:**

I can do a smooth version only for a square wave function, with a uniform width, but not the rectangle function.

```
smoothPulse[ePulse_, wup_, wdown_, smoothness_, t_] := 
 ePulse/2 + ePulse/\[Pi]*ArcTan[Sin[\[Pi] t/wup]*smoothness]
```

[image]

---

**Rectangle Pulse with 2 differents widths:**

I don't know the smooth version. I tried to build a smooth UnitBox version.

```
smoothunitbox[t_, sharpness_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Tanh[sharpness*(2 t + 1)] + 1, 
     t < 0}, {1 - Tanh[sharpness*(2 t - 1)], t >= 0}}]/2
smoothRectangle[h_, wup_, wdown_, smoothness_, t_] := 
 With[{period = wup + wdown, duty = wup/(wup + wdown)}, 
  h*smoothunitbox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty), smoothness]]

Plot[smoothRectangle[1, 2, 4, 20, t], {t, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None]
```

But the smooth is not good. How to improve?

[image]

Comment: There's some good examples for triangle, sawtooth, and square waves here already: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38295/72682

Comment: yes, I've read it. But the solution is only for square wave, not the rectangle function.

Comment: Right, I mis-read it. You could still try a $\tanh(x)$ compression to get a smooth alternative to `UnitBox` like in my now deleted answer. `smoothbox[t_, sharpness_] := Piecewise[{
    {Tanh[sharpness*(2 t + 1)] + 1, t < 0},
    {1 - Tanh[sharpness*(2 t - 1)], t >= 0}}]/2` and plot with: `Plot[{UnitBox[t], smoothbox[t, 15]}, {t, -2, 2}, Exclusions -> None]` however you would have to convert your pulse train to centers and widths first.

Comment: yes, it seems that is the only solution right now. We don't have a solution for the whole range. :) Post your answer and I will accept it. @flinty

Comment: Don't you just need a smooth `UnitStep` to construct a solution?  And to be clear, you want a box function, not a (periodic) pulse function?

Comment: I have tried the smooth UnitStep, but it only smooths at one side. I want a smooth periodic pulse function in the shape of a rectangle.

Comment: A symmetric, smoothed `UnitStep[t]` is given by `us[k_, t_] := (1 + Tanh[k t])/2` (with `k` a large enough constant for your purposes). The corresponding box function is `box[a_, b_, k_, t_] := us[k, t - a] - us[k, t - b]` (usually with `a < b` and `k` >> `b - a`). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function and substitute a smooth step function for $H$.

Comment: @MichaelE2, can you build the periodic rectangle pulse with your smooth UnitStep? I know the only way to do that is: `smoothRectangle[h_, wup_, wdown_, smoothness_, t_] := 
 With[{period = wup + wdown, duty = wup/(wup + wdown)}, 
  h*smoothunitbox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty), smoothness]]`    ---> but it only smooth one side ~.~

Comment: Plug `Mod[t/period, 1]` in for `t` into `box[..]`.

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't work. `smoothunitbox[t_, sharpness_] := (1 + Tanh[sharpness t])/2;
box[a_, b_, sharpness_, t_] := 
  N[Evaluate[
    smoothunitbox[t - a, sharpness] - 
     smoothunitbox[t - b, sharpness]]];
smoothRectangle[h_, wup_, wdown_, sharpness_, t_] := 
  With[{period = wup + wdown, duty = wup/(wup + wdown)}, 
   h*box[wup, wdown, sharpness, Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty)]];

Plot[smoothRectangle[1, 2, 3, 2, t], {t, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Can you make a full answer? I will accept your answer. @MichaelE2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `mollifier` in mathematics. It also work for the `Piecewise` function.

**Reply the comment**

```
a = 2;
b = 3;
S[x_ /; 0 <= x <= a] := 1;
S[x_ /; a <= x <= a + b] := 0;
S[x_ /; x >= a + b] := S[x - (a + b)];
S[x_ /; x <= a + b] := S[x + a + b];
ρ = 1/NIntegrate[Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], {x, -1, 1}];
φ[x_, ϵ_] = (ρ/ϵ)*  Piecewise[{{Exp[-ϵ^2/(ϵ^2 - x^2)], -ϵ < x < ϵ}}];
Plot[S[x], {x, -2 (a + b), 2 (a + b)}]
Plot[NIntegrate[φ[t - x, .3]*S[x], {x, -2 (a + b), 
   2 (a + b)}], {t, -2 (a + b), 2 (a + b)}]
```

[image]

**Updated**

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 2}}];
s[x_] = f[Mod[x, 4, -2]];
ρ = 1/NIntegrate[Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], {x, -1, 1}];
φ[x_, ϵ_] = (ρ/ϵ)*Piecewise[{{Exp[-ϵ^2/(ϵ^2 - x^2)], -ϵ < x < ϵ}}];
Plot[s[x], {x, -4, 4}]
Plot[NIntegrate[φ[t - x, .3]*s[x], {x, -4, 4}], {t, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

**Original**

But I don't know how to smooth the rectangle, I only try to smooth the `Abs` function.

```
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {-x, -1 <= x <= 0}}];
h[x_] = g[Mod[x, 2, -1]];
Plot[h[x], {x, -4, 4}]
ρ = 1/NIntegrate[Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], {x, -1, 1}];
φ[x_, ϵ_] = (ρ/ϵ)*Piecewise[{{Exp[-ϵ^2/(ϵ^2 - x^2)], -ϵ < x < ϵ}}];
Plot[NIntegrate[φ[t - x, 1/8]*h[x], {x, -4, 4}], {t, -4,4}]
```

[image]

Comment: can this method (NIntegrate) work with a rectangle? Have you tried?

Comment: Your update is a square wave function (with a width of 2). Can you plot a smooth version of a rectangle function with 2 widths: a, b.

Comment: @NamNguyen It is OK now?

Comment: Yes, your method is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want the square wave high 20% of the time. The following helps.

```
DutyCycle = 0.2; Plot[Piecewise[{{x/(2 DutyCycle), 
x < DutyCycle}, {(1 - 2 DutyCycle + x)/(2 - 2 DutyCycle), 
DutyCycle < 1}}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: piecewise linear plot]
Based on that we can make one period of our smooth square-wave by doing this.

```
singlePeriod[t_, Smoothness_, DutyCycle_] := Piecewise[{
{ArcTan[Sin[2 \[Pi] t/(2 DutyCycle)]*Smoothness]/
  ArcTan[Smoothness], t < DutyCycle},
{ArcTan[Sin[\[Pi] (1 - 2 DutyCycle + t)/(1 - DutyCycle)]*Smoothness]/
  ArcTan[Smoothness], DutyCycle < 1}
}];  Plot[singlePeriod[t, 12, 0.2], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: one period with 20% duty cycle.]
Make the above periodic using this:

```
smoothPulse[t_,Smoothness_,DutyCycle_]:=singlePeriod[Mod[t,1],Smoothness,DutyCycle]; Plot[smoothPulse[t,12,0.2],{t,0,4},PlotRange->All,Exclusions->None]
```

[image: periodic smooth square wave]

With appropriate use smoothPulse above, we can change the high-value, low-value, period, and phase of a smoothPulse. Here is an example:

```
Plot[2.5+2.5*smoothPulse[12t+0.2,12,0.2],{t,0,0.33333},PlotRange->All,Exclusions->None]
```

[image]