# Approximate the piecewise constant with a smooth function

Tags: regions, piecewise, discontinuity, smoothing

Let us first define a two regions as follow :

```
inner=1;outer=2;
reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, inner];
reg2 = Annulus[{0, 0}, {inner, outer}];
glass=1.5;air=1;
```

Now let's say I want to assign different values for a particular parameter(say refractive index) to the two different regions (say 1 for the region "reg1" and 2 for the region "reg2".I can do it as follow .Here I have also smoothened the piecewise function.

```
appro = With[{k = 100}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
ref[x_, y_] = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@If[x^2+y^2<=inner^2, glass, air] /.UnitStep -> appro ;
```

It returns the result as follow

```
ref[1.1, 0]
(*1.0167*)
```

Now in this case doing the smoothening is pretty easy because I can write the mathematical form  of the interface between the two regions easily.But for a complicated regions this is not so easy.So I can do the following thing.

```
ref[x_, y_] = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@ PiecewiseExpand@If[RegionMember[reg1, {x, y}], glass, air] /.  UnitStep -> appro ;
```

This returns the result as follow

```
ref[1.1, 0]
(*1.000*)
```

So this can't do the smoothening thing here.Can someone help me in figure out this thing where I can do the smoothening for complicated regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PiecewiseExpand` owns a second argument:

```
ref[x_, y_] = 
 Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
   PiecewiseExpand[If[RegionMember[reg1, {x, y}], glass, air], Reals] /.  
  UnitStep -> appro
```

> ```
> (* 1 + 0.5 (1/2 + ArcTan[100 (1 - x^2 - y^2)]/π) *)
> ```

Comment: thank you so much @xzczd

Answer (score 2):

Relate link : [Smooth Boxcar function (Rectangle Pulse function)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234063/smooth-boxcar-function-rectangle-pulse-function/234067#234067)

Here we also use mollifier      (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)  just a test,not so effect.

We chose a `ParametricRegion` `reg1` which can replace to other `ImplicitRegion` etc.
We can also adjust $\epsilon=10^-8$ to other small positive real number.

```
φ[x_, y_] = 
  Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - (x^2 + y^2))], x^2 + y^2 < 1}}];
const = NIntegrate[φ[x, 
    y], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞,∞}];
k[x_, y_, ϵ_ /; ϵ > 0] = 
  1/ϵ^2 φ[x/ϵ, y/ϵ]/const;
mollify[f_][ϵ_ /; ϵ > 0][x_, y_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   f[x - u, y - v] k[u, v, ϵ]*
    Boole[u^2 +v^2 < ϵ^2], {u, -ϵ, ϵ}, {v, -ϵ, ϵ}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
reg1 = ParametricRegion[{{s, (1 + t) s^2 - t}, -1 <= s <= 1 && 
     0 <= t <= 1}, {s, t}];
f[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1.5, {x, y} ∈ reg1}}, 1];
pts = {{.1, .2}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 10^-9}, {0, -0.2}};
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MaxRecursion -> 6, Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts]}]
mollify[f][10^-8] @@@ pts
```

> `{1., 1.01443, 1.25, 1.20265, 1.5}`

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer.But I think this method is not so efficient as ``Simplify`PWToUnitStep``..and takes a good amount of time.