# Generate a pulse with given rise and a fall time

Tags: plotting, functions

I need to generate a pulse with a given rise and fall time. Currently, I am using the command "UnitStep[t]-UnitStep[t-a]" to generate a pulse of width 'a'. But here I can't provide the rise and fall time. Is there any way to generate the required pulse?

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234063)

Comment: Would this do? `f[x_, start_, a_, rise_, fall_] = 
 Piecewise[{{0, x < start}, {(x - start)/rise, x < start + rise}, {1, 
    x < start + a - fall}, {(start + a - x)/fall, x <= start + a}, {0,
     x > start + a}}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber, this is fine. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
pulse[a_, t1_, t2_] := 0.5*((Tanh[x/t1] + 1) - (1 + Tanh[(x - a)/t2]));

Manipulate[
 Plot[pulse[a, t1, t2], {x, -5, 40}], {{a, 10}, 5, 20}, {{t1, 2}, 0.1,
   3}, {{t2, 2}, 0.1, 3}]
```

[image]

and play with the parameters a, t1 and t2 to choose ones of your liking.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is I needed.

Answer (score 3):

For some applications, I prefer using something like ["smoothstep"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) instead of $\tanh$. For this answer, however, I will instead use ["rational smoothstep"](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2019/03/28/on-a-rational-variant-of-smoothstep/) to implement a "smoothpulse" function:

```
smoothstep[n_Integer, x_] := #^n/(#^n + (1 - #)^n) &[Clip[x, {0, 1}]]

smoothpulse[n_Integer, a_, t1_, t2_, x_] :=
      smoothstep[n, (x + t1)/t1] - smoothstep[n, (x - a)/t2]
```

Slightly modifying Alexei's `Manipulate[]`, we have the following:

```
Manipulate[Plot[smoothpulse[n, a, t1, t2, x], {x, -5, 40}, PlotRange -> All],
           {{n, 2}, 1, 10, 1}, {{a, 10}, 5, 20}, {{t1, 2}, 0.1, 3}, {{t2, 2}, 0.1, 3}]
```

[image: Manipulate for "smoothpulse"]